# Existing TestFlight beta tester are not notified and newly added are notified

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, testflight, beta-testing

For the first time I made a app build to for beta testing in itunesconnect and I have added some external testers.It worked fine and the get notified.

But now I have updated new version for Beta testing and added more external tester.Only newly added tester are notified.Not the old external tester which were added for the first time when I was upload the app for the first version. . . . .

Any thing I am missing or to do something for it. . .

Comment: I think, you'd better ask this on Apple Dev Forums.

Comment: Hey @Anil do you have created group for some previous testers..?

Comment: no I have not created group for any @AvinashJadhav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Submitting app for external testing, you should list down all testers for the selected app version.
As you said all tester were added to previous version not received notification, this is because they were not added to list for external testing purpose for new build.
**Best practice:** 
1. Add all related testers to a particular group for Managing External Testers.
[image: Add All Related External testers to a Group]
Choose "Add Existing Tester"
[image]

2. Before start testing select all/any specific/none Tester Group. in addition to new one
[image]

3. Then Start Testing.

Comment: 2 nd time I have directly add testers with your 2nd step

Comment: Is it sent notification...?

Comment: Actually it has worked for me. Wait for some time it is expected to work for you as well

Answer (score 0):

In the latest testflight:

1. go to the build you want to test
2. remove the external testers group you need from the build
3. add the external testers group again to the build

in this case every tester will be notified again